# List index out of range when trying to import csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm having some issues when it comes to reading and writing csv files to Python, and the error is 'list index out of range'. I see other people have experienced this issue in Stackoverflow, but I can't find one specific to this problem.

In the first scenario, I create a new csv file using the **save_to_file()** method. Everything works, no problem.
Just to test if it works in reverse, I rename the '*list_of_friends.csv*' file  to '*friends.csv*', and call '**load_from_file()**' which I then get the error, list index is out of range. However, if I was to manually change the file in excel (i.e. adding/deleting names), it works fine once I try loading the file again.

In the second scenario, it is the complete opposite of the first scenario if I was to change the **delimiter=','**. In other words, I can read 'friends.csv' when copied and renamed from 'list_of_friends', but it doesn't work once I modify the *friends.csv* file with new names in excel.

I'm not too sure if it might be the configuration in my excel program itself?

```
class Friend:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, phone_number):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.phone_number = phone_number

    def print_info(self, index):
        print(f"\n {index}. {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()} {self.phone_number.title()}")


list_of_friends = []


def add_friends():
    print(" ")
    first_name = input("Enter the first name: ")
    last_name = input("Enter the last name: ")
    phone_number = input("Enter the phone number: ")
    new_friend = Friend(first_name.upper(), last_name.upper(), phone_number)
    list_of_friends.append(new_friend)
    print(f"\n{new_friend.first_name.title()} {new_friend.last_name.title()} has been added to the list \n")


def save_to_file():
    with open("list_of_friends.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
        csv_writer.writerow(["sep=,"])
        csv_writer.writerow(["First Name", "Last Name", "Phone number"])
        for friend in list_of_friends:
            csv_writer.writerow([friend.first_name.title(), friend.last_name.title(), friend.phone_number])
        list_of_friends.clear()
        print("\nSave successful")


def load_from_file():
    with open("friends.csv", "r") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        next(csv_reader)
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            new_friend = Friend(row[0].upper(), row[1].upper(), row[2].upper())
            list_of_friends.append(new_friend)
        print("\nLoad successful")
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. You are responsible for making an attempt to locate and diagnose the problem, and for isolating the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CSV stands for "comma separated file", but sometimes people prefer to use other characters to separate (aka delimit) the text. Python's `csv` function will allow you to change the delimiter.

In `save_to_file`, you create `csv.writer`, and you do not specify the delimiter. [It will default to a comma.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters).

You also include a line `sep=,` which presumably is to tell the reader that you are using a comma as a separator/delimiter. (Later you explicitly skip over the line so it isn't used.)

In `load_from_file`, you create a `csv_reader`, and tell it the delimiter is a semicolon. It doesn't consider the comma to be a delimiter.

As a result, it probably reads the entire line as one field. When you ask for the second field, it gives you an error.

---

Other suggestions:

- Instead of print_info, consider defining `__str__`. It will need to be printed, and it won't know about the index, but that's probably a good thing.
- Don't bother specifying the delimiter in the first line of the CSV. Most CSV readers won't know how to handle that.
- When you save in Excel, look at how you can override the use of semicolons to match the commas, or just standardise on semicolons (or whatever Excel uses).
- Look at `csv.DictWriter`. Then you don't need to write out the title line, don't need to skip lines, can start calling the fields by their names rather than their numbers.
- Why are you storing names in upper case? Why not store them as they are typed? Why not display them as they are typed? People's names often don't follow title case rules.
- Some people don't have a first name and last name.

Comment: Looks like you might want to include a link to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)